# Integrating a data from a tuple

Tags: python, integration

I am trying to do an integration on a set of data of the form of:
[  4.90601545e-06   1.25523477e-05  -1.34973044e-05 ] for my y value and

[      0.            1591.54943092    3183.09886184 ] for my x value
I am trying to use yi=cumtrapz(y,x) 
but I receive the following syntax error when it is trying to integrate.

```
Cumulatively integrate y(x) using the composite trapezoidal rule.
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am unsure how to resolve this issue as it claims to be on line 195 when my code only goes to around 80.

I am thinking it is due to my data type it cannot integrate but having limited experiences with coding and python in general I am unsure of this.

Any help is much appreciated.

I read in my data using a function:

```
 def stuff(filename):
    data=Strip(filename) 
    x,y=zip(*data) 
    return x,y
```

where stripper is a function that removes meta data from my actual document I am reading in my info from. 
data contains information of the form:

```
 [  0.00000000e+00  -1.60284679e-02]
 [  1.59154943e+03   2.91773817e-01]
 [  3.18309886e+03   6.21179811e-02]
```

Comment: Can you post all the code surrounding the call?

Comment: # hashtag your comments

Answer (score 0):

If you have `x` and `y` as separate lists or numpy arrays, code similar to the following will work:  (edited now for the function call)

```
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz
x,y=stuff(filename)
# x=( 0., 1591.54943092, 3183.09886184 )
# y=( 4.90601545e-06, 1.25523477e-05, -1.34973044e-05 )
auc=cumtrapz(y,x)
```

Comment: Sorry for any confusion with the data file I get my x and y data from another a list of tuples and have amended the original post to show this.